# Why is the email Intent not working from Common (non Activity) class

Tags: android, android-intent

This code works perfectly in the Activity Class, but if I move this code to Common (non Activity) class I'm getting this error:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Here is the code:

```
public static void emailIntend(Context context) {

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, null);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, context.getString(R.string.string_email_send_feedback_subject));
        String[] receipients = new String[1];
        receipients[0] = context.getString(R.string.string_email);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, receipients);

        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email to the developer..."));

    }
```

And this is how I am calling from the Activity:

```
 Common.emailIntend( getApplicationContext() );
```

I tried replacing `getApplicationContext()` with `this`, but no help.

Kindly, tell me if I am doing something not correct.

Comment: Please explain what "this does not works" means. Also, AFAIK, you need a `mailto:` `Uri` instead of `EXTRA_EMAIL` on `ACTION_SENDTO`.

Comment: @CommonsWare This is error I am getting `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?` Otherwise the codes fine in Activity class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` on the wrong Intent.
That, combined with using `getApplicationContext()`, is causing the error.

The call to `Intent.createChooser()` returns a new Intent, and that's the one that needs the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag, since it's the one that you're passing to `startActivity()`.

Note that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` wasn't needed if I passed in an Activity context to the method (`this` in the Activity);

Also note that I also had to modify your code a bit to get the chooser to work correctly, your original code didn't work for me, even in an Activity.

The following code works for me, even using `getApplicationContext()` as the context passed in:

```
public static void sendEmail(Context context){
    String uriText =
            "mailto:test@gmail.com" +
                    "?subject=" + Uri.encode("test subject");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);

    Intent i = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email to the developer...");
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

References:

[ACTION_SENDTO for sending an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132889/action-sendto-for-sending-an-email/5522616#5522616)

[startActivity within a subclass of Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746274/startactivity-within-a-subclass-of-application)